# How is downcasting/upcasting done between 2 interfaces in Selenium WebDriver in Java in Excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jxl

Interface `WritableSheet`  extends  interface `Sheet` (jxl) library.   I want to use the `addCell()` that is there in
`WritableSheet`.

But when I try to convert `Sheet` object to `WritableSheet` object,I get `ClassCastException`. I want to know how to typecast between two interfaces.

Below is my code :

```
package xyz;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import jxl.Cell;  
import jxl.Sheet;  
import jxl.Workbook;  
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;  
import jxl.write.Label;  
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;  
import jxl.write.WriteException;  
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;  
public class WriteExcel12  
{   
   public static Workbook wb;  
   public static Sheet s;  
   public static Cell c;  
   public static WritableSheet ws;  
   public static Label l;  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException  
    {  
        File f=new File("D:/Input.xls");
        wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
        s=wb.getSheet("Data");

        //WritableSheet extends Sheet
        ws=(WritableSheet)s;//ClassCastException here

        //Read cell(0,0) from Sheet named Data
        c=s.getCell(0,0);
        String a=c.getContents();

        //Read cell(0,1) from Sheet named Data
        c=s.getCell(1,0);
        String b=c.getContents();

        //Read cell(0,2) from Sheet named Data
        c=s.getCell(2,0);
        String d=c.getContents();

        //Convert String to integer
        int e=Integer.parseInt(a);
        System.out.println(e);

        int g=Integer.parseInt(b);
        System.out.println(g);

        int h=Integer.parseInt(d);
        System.out.println(h);

        //Perform addition
        int result=e+g+h;
        System.out.println(result);

        //Convert result which is it to String
        String ans=Integer.toString(result);

        // Write String  ans to cell(0,3)
        l=new Label(3,0,ans);
        ws.addCell(l);
    }
}
```

---

> Data.xls
>
> 10| 20| 30|

---

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `WritableWorkbook` from your `Workbook`.Then you can get your `WritableSheet` .

```
File f=new File("D:/Input.xls");
wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(f, workbook);
WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet("Data");
```

Comment: ,I tried the above code.My sheet named **Data**  in **Input.xls**  is overwritten by a sheet named **Input** and the sheet is empty.